# Having trouble in for custom listview adapter class

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I try to create a class which extends SimpleAdapter and overwrite the getView() method to prevent the color change problem (when the first item recycle to the bottom, the color will also appear again)for my listview. However, I write in this way:

public class Adapter extends SimpleAdapter {

```
    public Adapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
            int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_textview = null;
        TextView txt_distance = null;
        TextView txt_starimage = null;
        ImageView txt_imageview = null;
    }

    HashMap<Integer, View> lmap = new HashMap<Integer, View>();

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ViewHolder holder = null;


        if (lmap.get(position) == null) {
            view =LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_bank_listview_item,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt_starimage = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.bank_listview_starimage);
            holder.txt_imageview = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.bank_listview_imageview);
            holder.txt_distance = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.bank_listview_distance);
            holder.txt_textview = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.bank_listview_textview);

            lmap.put(position, view);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            view = lmap.get(position);
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        return view;
    }


}
```

But the listview only appear first page listview items, and the following pages are empty(only contain empty layout). How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
if (lmap.get(position) == null) {
```

You should check whether the convertView is null or not. If it's null, you need to inflate a new view. If it's not, you should reuse it.

e.g.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   ViewHolder holder;
   if (convertView == null){
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       init(convertView, holder); // findViewById stuff
       convertView.setTag(holder);
   } else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   setView(position, holder, convertView); // fill in the textviews, set background color etc.
   return convertView;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I have have trouble for the "context"(context.getSystemService...) in  
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
which show context can not be resolved...

Comment: To use the context, you need to store it in a local variable in the adapter constructor.

Comment: Such as: public Adapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) { private Context context; super(context, data, resource, from, to); // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub }... at the beginning? Thanks for your help again!!

Comment: I take back local. Define a variable in your adapter class, so that it can be accessed by all of the methods defined in it. Store context to the variable you defined in constructor.